# Overwriting HTML in one .CSV file with cmd.exe + regexp

Tags: regex, batch-file, csv

Our company maintain HTML pages templates in one .CSV file, with “;” separating HTML pages (one full web site on each line of .CSV).
Web sites will be generated with one batch file by, in a first step overwriting the HTML templates with variables also stored in same .CSV (beginning of lines), and in a second step exporting HTML pages.
HTML strings to be replaced in templates are identified with placeholders, !pageID.tagID.attribute! , and tens of variables are declared with syntax  %pageID.tagID.attribute=value% at beginning of each line, just before HTML content (one site per line).
I’m stuck with my cmd.exe batch file writing, due to lack of good regexp skills.
Who can find the right regexp pattern (starting with ^ and ending with $) that will overwrite my HTML templates with my variables values. 
I intend to use findrepl.bat utility  http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697  to allow WSH/VBS regexp. Powershell could be used for .NET advanced regexp ($matches object ?) 
Many thanks in advance. Good reward from my boss …

EXAMPLE : one LINE of the .CSV file
%AA.line1.href=Microsoft.com%    %AA.line1.txt=Hello%    %AB.warning.css =red%    ……  etc (about 50 variables)   ;   '<' body'>' … '<'a href=! AA.line1.href! '>'<' strong'> !AA.line1.txt! '<'/strong'>'<'span>World'<'/span'>'<'/a'>' … '<'/body'>'; '<'body'>' …  '<'section style=”color:!AB.warning.css!” '>'Read please'<'/section'>'  … '<'/body'>';   ….. etc.  (about 20 HTML pages templates)

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation was slightly unclear, but from what I gather, you have a large file with many strings. In these strings, there are small sets of variables enclosed by exclamation points.

This Regex should extract each one of the variables from that string (The pageID, tagID, and attribute).

- `!\w+.` will capture the pageID (along with the exclamation and period)
- `.\w+.` will capture the tagID (along with the encompassing periods)
- `.\w+!` will capture the attribute (along with the period and trailing exclamation)